how to use “psql --dbname ”when password has kesword @
I want to use psql to exec ./my_test.sql(which is on my local windows) on linux pg.
I use --dbname to connect the db,but my password('z987xSst@@gres') has kesword "@" which leading a error like this:
psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:z987xSst@@gres@ip:5432/postgres -A -t -q -f ./my_test.sql

-- psql: error: Unable to interpret host name "@gres@ip" to address: Unknown server error

I tried to use backslashes to do this (z987xSst\@\@gres), but it didn't work.
I want to know what I need to do to make it work, or if there's another way. (Preferably, I don't have to enter the password manually, like --dbname str.)

Did you try to put it in quotes? What when you use --password option and the url/connection string without your password. e.g. psql --dbname="postgresql://<username>@<ip>..." --password. Do not specify the password, wait psql asks for it.

Why do you put your password in the connection string? Use .pgpass or something else that is safe. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

@Marc Thanks for your answer. I know the option --password, it must enter the password later ,but I don't want to.

@FrankHeikens Thanks for your reply. Actually i do it befor. But I only user .pgpass on linux, not windows. When I make the file in C:\Users\Administrator\.pgpass, it not work. I think it maybe not  be use on windows.
After your answer, I read the document again. The style has problem, which leading the inline code at the end of the paragraph. See https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/doc/src/sgml/libpq.sgml#L1289-L1295.
And this config %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf is effective.

To my knowledge .pgpass also works on Windows. It has been a while that I touched a Windows machine, but back in the days it worked just fine.

You must encode the special characters, so @ becomes %40

It work, thank you very much.
